# Spring Boot mongoRepository query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have this data `[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Lakshya2",
        "email": "lakshya.punhani2@gmail.com",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "description": "qwerty",
                "rate": "20",
                "name": "AC"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Lakshya",
        "email": "lakshya.punhani@gmail.com",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "description": "qwerty",
                "rate": "20",
                "name": "AC"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "description": "desc",
                "rate": "10",
                "name": "BBG"
            }
        ]
    }
]`

I am new to spring boot and mongo db as well so i just need to know how to get a particular product by user id and product id.

This is what I tried but its giving incorrect data

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>
{   
    Product findByproducts_productId(String productId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use following query.

@Query(value = "{ 'users.id' : ?0, 'products.id' : ?1 }")
List findByproductsByUserIdAndproductId(String userId, String productId);